# Rename multiple files simultaneously in visual studio 10?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have many `.aspx` files with filename containing some string "xyx" in solution explorer of visual studio 10. I want to rename all files with filename in which "xyz" replaced with "opq" simultaneously.

Can anybody suggest how to accomplish this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of no way to do this from within the IDE but it *can* be done outside.

First off, close your solution(s) that contain all the files you want to rename so as to not cause any angst to Visual Studio.

The get yourself a copy of `prename` for Windows, or [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/), or [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php), or some other program which can rename mass files intelligently.

That will take care of the actual renaming.

The next phase is to got through all the affect `vcxproj` and `vcxproj.filter` files (using a decent editor that can bulk search-replace, or a text processing tool like `awk` or `perl`), making the same changes that were done by the bulk renaming.

Unless you have massively complex project dependencies, this should be relatively easy.

Once both those steps are done, the project file references and actual files on the disk should agree, and you can re-open your solution.

If anything went wrong, just restore all the files from the backup I told you to take back in paragraph number ... :-)